# What should I know before upgrading this electrical switchboard?

Tags: electrical

I have this very old switchboard, I want to upgrade it to prepare for the following changes:

1. Install of a home battery system
2. Ensure that I can install an induction cooktop in the kitchen

As you can see in the picture, there is not a lot of room in the switchboard. The material in the board is quite old and contain asbestos.

What should I need to know or request the electrician to do about upgrading this switchboard?

The location is Sydney, Australia.

[image]

Comment: Could make some room by unbundling the antenna wire and relocating that antenna (lowest black item on the left with the shiny bracket.)

Comment: Asbestos hardboard is harmless if no micro-fibers are involved (it's not fluffy and you're not making dust). Don't sand it, drill it wet, mop up any shards in paper towels and throw it in the trash. The best enclosure for electrical gear is steel (I do not understand plastic consumer units WTH?)

Comment: And honestly I don't see any way to put all the stuff you list into such a small enclosure.  I would demo the enclosure and put something else in. If all your gear is plastic-cased, then get a steel cabinet.